# With Selenium python, do I need to refresh the page when waiting for hidden btn to appear and be clickable?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I'm trying to make a small program that looks at a web page at a hidden button (uses hide in the class) and waits for it to be clickable before clicking it. The code is below. I'm wondering if the `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable` functions will already by refreshing things or if I would have to manually refresh the page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(<URL>)

print("beginning 120s wait")
time.sleep(120)
print("finished 120s wait")

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "btn add"))

    )
    print("It went through")
    element.click()
    driver.execute_script("alert('It went through!');")
finally:
    driver.execute_script("alert('Did it work?');")
```

First of all, I am not really sure if just searching by the class name minus the "hide" part will actually find the correct element, but the larger issue is that I do not know if the button will only be visible after refreshing the page. If I need to refresh, then it gets annoying because most sites throw up additional captchas for both Firefox or Chrome when they figure out a bot is accessing the site. (That's why I have the initial sleep: so that I can finish any captcha manually first)

So, do I need to have a refresh in my code, or will it be fine without it? If I do need it, how do I implement it? Do I just add it like:

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(
        drive.refresh()
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "btn add"))

    )
```

And sorry if this has been answered elsewhere, I searched a bunch, but I have not quite found the answer on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use `sleep` the `WebDriverWait` with the correct `EC` will do the trick.

As for the `EC.element_to_be_clickable` this is the code behind the function:

```
def element_to_be_clickable(locator):
    """ An Expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that
    you can click it."""
    def _predicate(driver):
        element = visibility_of_element_located(locator)(driver)
        if element and element.is_enabled():
            return element
        else:
            return False

    return _predicate
```

As you can see the `EC.element_to_be_clickable` function **does not refresh the browser**.

If you insist you need the refresh the correct way to implement it will be:

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "btn add"))

except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException):
    driver.refresh()
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "btn add"))
```

I don't think the refresh will help with the hidden element...

Comment: So, EC.element_to_be_clickable will be fine without refreshing?

Comment: Yes sir! the `element_to_be_clickable` just waits for X amount of time until the element is fully visible and then that it's enabled.

Comment: Ok, that's how I understood it, but I guess I don't know how these pages actually get updated. If an element/button gets enabled, does it happen live? Say there is a greyed out button. How is the front-end dev changing things to make the change live? Does that "update" not need a refresh of the page to show up, or would it just suddenly appear on our end? The button I am waiting for functions like that. I don't think it just has logic that dictates it waits for a condition in React or something, though I may be wrong about that. So, a button being enabled can happen without a refresh?

Comment: @infinity8-room Usually there is some call-back function (or a listener) that will enable the button, for instance, if there are mandatory fields to fill the submit button will be disabled until all mandatory fields are filled. In most cases not only the refresh won't make the button enabled rather you will lose the condition to make it enabled. The wait for `EC` will wait for that reaction to happen. hope you find this helpful...

Comment: I do, thank you! The button in question from me will not activate in response to anything the user does.